# What is the error along with this code of GPIO

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

This Programming is based on the   L293D motor driver.
For example pins in the Pi 16,18,22 are the pins associated with the motors of one side.
It has pinA and pinB used to turn the on either directions pinE enables the motor which is at the pin22

```
from time import sleep
import thread
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
class Motion:
    #this class is used to define the different motion of the wheel.
    def __init__(self,pinA,pinB,pinE):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        Motor1A = pinA;
        Motor1B = pinB;
        Motor1E = pinE;
        GPIO.setup(Motor1A,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(Motor1B,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(Motor1E,GPIO.OUT)
    def forward(self):
        print "Moving Forward"
        GPIO.output(Motor1A,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(Motor1B,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.cleanup()
    sleep(2)
    def backword(self):
        print "Moving Backword"
        GPIO.output(Motor1A,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(Motor1B,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.cleanup()
    sleep(2)
    def stop(self):
        print "No Movements, Stoped"
        GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Good question, _what is the error?_. I can't see any

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that you call `GPIO.cleanup()` after every method. This also cleans up the GPIO pin numbering system you set with `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)` and so would cause problems if you call the methods more than once. It would be better to call `GPIO.cleanup()` only once at the end of your script. In the methods you could for example turn the pins low after a sleep to stop the motors after running them for the desired time.

If you post the actual error(s) you see when running your code, someone might be able to help you debug it further.